# How to organize your system for multiple projects?

Tags: filesystems, backup

I'm looking for a way to manage multiple system setups. As an example, if I start working on a project I might need to install some software and its dependencies. I would like when I finish working in this project to be able to revert the system to its previous state.

My ideal situation would be like having git but for the whole system, thus being able to create branches, experiment, and revert to any point in time.

Is there are a way to achieve this? I've thought about using LVM snapshots, is this a good idea?

Comment: Fixed. Yes, I'm looking for advice. I've been reading and cannot figure out if there is a standard way or any best practices for managing what I'm describing.

Comment: One word: virtual machines.

Comment: I thought about that too. I could run a very lightwave operative system to host a virtual machine. But I don't know why it doesn't sound that good for me, it feels like I would be loading my computer for someting that I could do without virtualization. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Is there like a dedicated operative system for managing virtual machines? I've read about Type 1 hypervisor: hypervisors that run directly on the system hardware. Do you know any good suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you need that? On my Linux distro, I just install required packages and keep them. Perhaps you want [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/), not exactly what you are dreaming of, but somehow close. Perhaps you want containers, like [docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software))

Comment: @ilkkachu Actually thats 2 words but it would be my advice as well i'm using fedora and virtualize a lot of systems

Comment: @aldr so you use fedore as host, and the run virtual machine. What do you suggest me, virtual box?

Comment: @WooWapDaBug basically I didnt know a lot about virtualization. What helped me was the yt channel of Level1Linux very detailed information about am4 systems I did set up my vms on. I can only recommend it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR
Use [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org) snapshots.

Virtual machine snapshots are most commonly used for that sort of requirement. The main reasons are simplicity, and the worst case scenario is zeroing all data root can write. If you have modern development box with 12+GB RAM and 8TB Disk space you might run 5-10 test environments at the same time and store 800 snapshots which is plenty.

On the other hand if testing is relatively tame, the common option is just to keep a log of actions (`apt install x y z && mkdir project0`) and undo them (`apt purge x y z && rm -r project0`) or just leave them if they are not interfering with other projects.

brtfs is an interesting option because it can provide a snapshot diff to a backup server efficiently, the disadvantage is that it's slightly more complicated, and much less stable.

There are many other options ( git/lvm/rsync/rdiffbackup/zfs/[containers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization)/etc ) but there are disadvantages (like extra time/space or less robust). At the end of the day quality developer time is the most sought commodity so the less time you spend on planning and environment setup the more time you have to be productive. So start with one of the 2 simple options and only if you find time is wasted explore a more complex solution.

Comment: I thought about that too. I could run a very lightwave operative system to host a virtual machine. But I don't know why it doesn't sound that good for me, it feels like I would be loading my computer for someting that I could do without virtualization. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Is there like a dedicated operative system for managing virtual machines? I've read about Type 1 hypervisor: hypervisors that run directly on the system hardware. Do you know any good suggestion?

Comment: My only problem with this solution is that it is something that I've already tryed in the past, and I wasn't happy about it. Virtual Box run slow in my computer, and it's quite a decent one (8gb ram, SSD, i7).

Comment: For me it is more that under normal load, a terminal an a web browser, my laptop's cpu is around 40 degrees and I'm consuming 20 W. When I use the virtual machine, cpu temperature goes to 65 C and 50 W.

Comment: @WooWapDaBug that's an indirect measurement, and seems more than expected. If you want more efficient without looking into the cause You could use a shared kernel solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization